# KendoUI WCF Services Demo Sources

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Where can I find de source files of the Nothwind WCF services used in the KendoUI Grid Demos.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some samples in Code Libraries. This is not the Demo sources but it helps a lot.

Thanks anyway